# How to understand nest and inherit

Tags: ruby

Why do `C` and `D` below select different `Par`, and how is it relevant to the mechanism of nest and inherit in Ruby?

```
class A
  Par = 4
end

class B
  Par = 2
  class C < A
    def show; Par end
  end
end

class B::D < A
  def show; Par end
end

B::C.new.show #=> 2
B::D.new.show #=> 4
```

Comment: Add your outputs of `puts cc.show` and `puts dd.show`

Comment: @Stefan, where is your answer? :)

Comment: Constant lookup is different when using `::`, see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Constants